# Does as? in a if statement insure that the instance inside the block isn't null inside all the if block?

Tags: android, kotlin, casting

I know that if i assign the *as?* to a variable so the compiler won't bother about safe cast issue.
For example:

```
w:Wolf? = Wolf()
wolf = w as? Wolf
```

Now i can use variable *wolf* to call any public member of *Wolf* without using a question mark (no need for safe call)

**but** if the as? is inside an if block and *item* variable not being assign. For example:

```
  if (item as? CountryDataItem != null)
    {
           // code that is using *item*
    }

    else{
   }
```

Does the code inside the *if block* can use item as a *CountryDataItem* without a need of cast and without the compiler remarking about safe calls when using the *CountryDataItem*
The question is from the reason that the item isn't being save in any variable so i'm not sure how the compiler consider him?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes. The compiler knows that if `item` is null then the control will never enter the `if` block and thus `item` is smart casted to `CountryDataItem`.

However, what you are doing is unnecessary. You should use `is` instead. Like so:

```kotlin
if (item is CountryDataItem) {
    // code that is using *item*
}
```

The above is only true if the field `item` is `val`. If `item` is a `var` then the compiler will not smart cast it to `CountryDataItem` as it may be updated elsewhere. In such a case, you will want to use a local variable. Like so:

```
val myItem = item 
if (myItem is CountryDataItem) {
    // code that is using *myItem*
} else {
   ...
}
```

or

```kotlin
val myItem = item as? CountryDataItem
if (myItem != null) {
    // code that is using *myItem*
} else {
    ...
}
```

Comment: i understood the sometimes the will prevent us from doing the way you wrote it, it will say that he can't guarantee that the in a different place the item was set to null between the if check and the block of the if

Comment: Ohh so your field `item` is a `var` and may be updated in some other part of your application. I have updated my answer

Comment: does the way i wrote the code isn't ok? Do i have to save the reference in a local variable in order to "enjoy" the smart cast and to be sure that the variable isn't equal to null?

Comment: although i didn't assign the result of *item as? CountryDataItem* it will be cast to *CountryDataItem* inside if block body?

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but I think the behavior of as? is a little different

When you do `wolf = w as? Wolf`, `wolf` still is a nullable `Wolf?`, so you still need `wolf?.method()`

`wolf = w as Wolf` would make wolf a non nullable `Wolf`, but the code would throw an exception if `w` is null

That is what I undestood from the docs

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html#safe-nullable-cast-operator

Comment: but in my code, before the block body i have checked the *item as? CountryDataItem* against null, before using him

Comment: Luiz means your ``wolf`` example - ``w as? Wolf`` evaluates to *either* the non-null ``Wolf`` type *or* null, so the resulting type is the nullable ``Wolf?`` (because it could be ``Wolf`` or null). So you still have to null check it with ``?``